# Finding $\lim_{x\to +\infty} (e^x\sin(e^{-x}\sin x))/x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the limit of $$\frac{e^x \sin(e^{-x}\sin x)}{x}$$ as $x\to +\infty$, I can't use l'Hopital method nor derivatives
Please help me

Comment: "sen" is the sine, right?

Comment: I meant sinx yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x \rightarrow \infty$, it is evident that $e^{-x} \sin(x) \rightarrow 0$ since $\sin(x)$ is bounded in $[-1,1]$ and $e^{-x} \to 0$. Multiply and divide by $e^{-x} \sin(x)$. We have:
$$\frac{\sin(x).\sin(e^{-x} \sin(x))}{x.e^{-x} \sin(x) }  $$ Now, as $x \rightarrow \infty$, we know that $\frac {\sin(e^{-x} \sin(x)}{e^{-x}\sin(x)}$ will approach $1$. So, the limit is now $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$ which is $0.$ Finally, you have your answer as $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Start multiplying both numerator and denominator by Exp[-x] and simplify. Can you continue from here ?

Comment: I've tried to continue but I can't find the limit

Comment: @Dipok. To what did you arrive ?

Comment: I arrived to sin(e^(-x)*sinx)/(x*e^-x)